# How to debug a mongoose action within node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, debugging, mongoose

I am using mongoose to connect mongoDB and my node.js app. However, when I create or update a model instance, it won't change the Database, how can I go inside to debug what happens in the `create` or `update` action? I do check the MongoDB interface, `delete` and `find` and `list` action works just fine:

Here are those two docs that I have:

```
// index.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const User = require('../model/user')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;


// connect to DB
const db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myImportantDates', {
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true, 
});

// create a user
const addUser = (user) =>{
    let newUser = new User(user)
    if (newUser.save()){
        console.log(newUser) // it will console.log the newly created user, but it is not in the database 
        mongoose.disconnect()
    }else{
        console.log(newUser.errors)
    }
}



// list all users
const listAllUsers = () =>{
    User.find().then((users)=>{
        console.log("Totally there are " + users.length + " users.");
        console.log(users);
        mongoose.disconnect();
    }).then(()=>process.exit())
}

// find one user
const findUserByEmail = (email) => {
    User.find({email},(err,docs)=>{
      if(err){
          console.log(err)
      }else{
          console.log(`Already found ${docs.length} matches.` )
          console.log(docs)
      }
      mongoose.disconnect()
    })
}


// update a user and make sure pass {new:true} option so that the doc in callback return the doc after updated
const updateUser = (email,user) => {
    User.findOneAndUpdate( { email }, user, { new: true }, (err,doc) =>{
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
          return
      }else{
          console.log(doc)
      }
      mongoose.disconnect()
    })
}


// remove a user
const deleteUser = email => {
   User.deleteOne( { email },(err,res) =>{
     if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return           
    }
       console.log("Deleted Successfully.");
       mongoose.disconnect()
       })

}



module.exports = {
    addUser,
    listAllUsers,
    findUserByEmail,
    updateUser,
    deleteUser
}
```

```
//user_methods.js

const { program } = require('commander');
const {addUser,listAllUsers,findUserByEmail,updateUser,deleteUser} = require('./model_methods/user_methods')
const inquirer = require('inquirer')

const questions = [
  {
    type: 'input',
    name: 'name',
    message: 'user name'
  },
    {
      type: 'input',
      name: 'email',
      message: 'user email'
    },
    {
      type: 'input',
      name: 'password',
      message: 'user password'
    },
  ];


program
.version('0.0.1')
.description("testing");


program
    .command('list')
    .alias('l')
    .description('List all users')
    .action(()=>listAllUsers())

program
   .command('add')
   .alias('a')
   .description('Add a user')
   .action(()=>{
    inquirer.prompt(questions)
    .then( answers => {
       addUser(answers)
     }).then(() => {
       process.exit()
     })
     .catch(err =>{
       console.log(error) 
     })
    })

program
  .command('find <email>')
  .alias('f')
  .description('find a user through email')
  .action((email)=>{
     findUserByEmail(email)
  })

program
  .command('update <email>')
  .alias('u')
  .description('update a user through email')
  .action((email)=>{
    inquirer.prompt(questions)
    .then( ( email,answers ) => {
       updateUser(email, answers)
     }).then(() => {
       process.exit()
     })
     .catch(err =>{
       console.log(error) 
     })
    })

program
  .command('delete <email>')
  .alias('d')
  .description('delete a user through email')
  .action((email)=>{
      deleteUser(email)
  })


program.parse(process.argv)
```

I will run `node index.js <command>` to reach those methods.

Comment: `mongoose.set('debug', true)`. This will log all the methods and arguments in the console. Also, can you tell me  from where you are making the call to `addUser` function

Comment: Also, are you establishing a connection through Mongoose at some point before making the call?

Comment: @Vishnu I attach the original docs there. I run `node index.js add` to call `adduser` . Can you check it out when you have time please?

Comment: @rb612 I did in `user_methods.js`, I attach the original docs here. Can you check it out when you have time please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the `process` is getting exited before the save happens. According to your current code, it looks like you don't need to call the `process.exit()` explicitly. The application will exist on its own when the `addUser` operation is completed.

Also, you need to update the `addUser` method. You should only close the connection after successfully saving the record

```js
// create a user
// create a user
const addUser = (user) =>{
    let newUser = new User(user)
    newUser.save((err, result) => {
        console.log("inside save method")
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else {
            console.log(result);
            mongoose.disconnect();
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it actually works! But my question is that I understand `process.exit()` is unnecessary now but when I call `process.exit()`, I chained it though in the `then` block, doesn't it mean it will quit ONLY after the previous step finished?

Comment: For that to work as expected the `addUser` function should return a promise. But currently `addUser` is an async function. so next `then` block which is having the `process.exit()` gets executed before that

Comment: Is it because `newUser.save()` returns a promise, so when I evaluate `newUser.save()` in the `if` block, it returns true??

Comment: Oh thanks Vishnu so that means in the current code, the `addUser` will `console.log` the `newUser` before it gets saved, and then it will return sth back to the previous process and the process will think it is done so that it moves to the next `then` block?

Comment: According to current code newUser.save() will be `Promise { <pending> }` when the `if (newUser.save())`  returns `true`, so it executes the below code and return before promise is resolved. mongoose save operation returns a promise unless you pass a callback. So if you return `newUser.save()` in the `addUser` method and add a return statement in `then` like this `.then(answers => { return addUser(answers)})`. I think your current implementation will work